# css - margin top causes unwanted body scroll bar

Tags: css

I have a situation where i need to keep `html, body {height:100%;}` while adding margin or position relative to the `.content` so that it pushes down 30px from top.
The problem is that doing this causes scrollbars to appear on the right.
The height of `.content` will change so there might be scrollbars if the height is increased.

How can i fix this so that i get rid of the side scrollbars when `.content` does not have increased height without forcing `overflow-y: hidden;`?

heres my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/5bwBx/

html:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='header'></div>
    <div class='content'></div>
    <div class='footer'></div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
html, body {height:100%;}
#container{height:100%; width:400px; margin:0 auto; background-color:grey;}
    .header{ height:20px; width:400px; background-color:red;}
    .content{ height:200px; width:400px;  position:relative; top:30px; background-color:blue; }
    .footer{ height:20px; width:400px; background-color:green;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution, `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` on the body. 
 The reason of this, is to reset all the defauls set on the margins and paddings.

```
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5bwBx/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it has nothing to do with that. The scrollbar is being added because of the default margin on the `body`. By default the `body` is set to `margin:8px` - in Chrome anyways.

Simply set `body { margin:0px; }` to remove it.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FhzEC/) - the vertical scrollbar is removed.