# Issue with scrollbars when centering my div with css top and left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried looking up an answer to my issue and found this [css - margin top causes unwanted body scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695305/css-margin-top-causes-unwanted-body-scroll-bar) but it doesn't seem to fix my issue.

Here is my code to center

```
   if(W > H)
            {
                scale = (height-45) / H;
            }

            else if(H > W)
            {
                scale = (width-5) / W;
            }

            var left = (width*0.5)-(0.5*W*scale);
            var top =  ((height+40)*0.5)-(0.5*H*scale);

$("#plan").css({"position":"absolute", "left": left,"top": top});
```

Basically I am centering my div's center in the center of the screen, and I am having 2 issues.

1. I have it set so that there is a scale for my div, that is based on the smaller of height or width, and in the example I have a 1285x910 div.  My height will be maxed out, but I still get scrollbars.  The horizontal is also there.
2. Using the same example as above there is a horiz scrollbar, that if I scroll over, will bring me over to the left a random amount, for each of my plants it's different.  1 brought it over to make the plan 0,0, the next made it so that it made the plan's center be at 0,0.

When I switched from position"relative" to "absolute" it changed one plan to only scroll a little bit, but it's still there.

So basically (in this example) I am looking to stop the verticle scrollbar for appearing since there is nothing to scroll, and by the scrollbars being there it takes up too much room and it's not full screen anymore.

As well as stop the horizontal scrollbar from appearing when my plan is centered and not big enough to scroll.  If my plan is big enough and needs to scroll left or right, that should be allowed and enabled.

The answer in the above link is

"One simple solution, margin:0; and padding:0; on the body. 
The reason of this, is to reset all the defauls set on the margins and paddings.

```
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

"

Which seems to be what I want to do for at least #1, but if it works for #2, that would be great (i.e., I want my div to be centered but it to be as if nothing was moved so it doesn't throw off the scrollbars, unless it got big enough to do so, or it was big enough to do so based on it's size).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lh3ze3m6/18/

Any comments or questions please let me know,

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

To disable both horizontal and vertical scrollbars apply this to your css stylesheet:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about that trick, but that still allows the scrollbars to function i.e., if I used the middle button I can still scroll, as well as mobile also scrolling.  From the link above it says 

One simple solution, margin:0; and padding:0; on the body. 
The reason of this, is to reset all the defauls set on the margins and paddings.

html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}

I am having issues with that, but that seems to be what I am looking for, but need to fix it.

Basically I want my center to be as if it's 0,0, and not throw off scrollbars, as well as the vert sb.

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle? Also you want to disable scrolling all together?

Comment: Yeah am trying to whip one up, will get that out also.

I don't want to disable scrolling, it's as I mentioned I want to "reset" my margins (like the above example explains), with my div being centered (as if it was in 0,0 i.e., the default pos so no scroll bars should activate), as well as when my size is maxed (i.e., <=100% height or width) scrollbars shouldn't activate.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh okay, have you looked into browser resets, like eric mayers reset.css or normalize.css?

Comment: Updated post with fiddle, normalize nor reset worked.

Also for some reason the fiddle isn't working properly.  I cannot get the div to move using the css top and left, maybe you can figure it out, but it works for me, I don't know why it isn't working in the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/Lh3ze3m6/18/